# How to parse dates in multiple formats using SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, parsing, datetime, simpledateformat

I am trying to parse some dates that are coming out of a document. It would appear users have entered these dates in a similar but not exact format.

here are the formats:

```
9/09
9/2009
09/2009
9/1/2009
9-1-2009
```

What is the best  way to go about trying to parse all of these? These seem to be the most common, but I guess what is hanging me up is that if i have a pattern of "M/yyyy" wont that always catch before "MM/yyyy"  Do I have to set up my try/catch blocks nested in a least restrictive to most restrictive way? it seems like it sure is going to take a lot of code duplication to get this right.

Comment: Well, you could just have a list of patterns, and then a simple loop to keep trying until you hit one that works.

Comment: And then simply break the loop?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You'll need to use a different `SimpleDateFormat` object for each different pattern. That said, you don't need that many different ones, [thanks to this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

> **Number:** For formatting, the number of pattern letters is the minimum number of digits, and shorter numbers are zero-padded to this amount. For parsing, the number of pattern letters is ignored unless it's needed to separate two adjacent fields.

So, you'll need these formats:

- `"M/y"` (that covers `9/09`, `9/2009`, and `09/2009`)
- `"M/d/y"` (that covers `9/1/2009`)
- `"M-d-y"` (that covers `9-1-2009`)

So, my advice would be to write a method that works something like this (**untested**):

```
// ...
List<String> formatStrings = Arrays.asList("M/y", "M/d/y", "M-d-y");
// ...

Date tryParse(String dateString)
{
    for (String formatString : formatStrings)
    {
        try
        {
            return new SimpleDateFormat(formatString).parse(dateString);
        }
        catch (ParseException e) {}
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Many of the answers here are offering some form of this as a solution, but it unfortunately will not work. If the string being parsed matches format #3, it's very likely that the SimpleDateFormat will successfully parse with format #1, but you will have the wrong date.

Comment: Though this question is about date, this doesn't work for me for milliseconds: `S` doesn't parse `000`.

Answer (score 28):

What about just defining multiple patterns? They might come from a config file containing known patterns, hard coded it reads like:

```
List<SimpleDateFormat> knownPatterns = new ArrayList<SimpleDateFormat>();
knownPatterns.add(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"));
knownPatterns.add(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm.ss'Z'"));
knownPatterns.add(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"));
knownPatterns.add(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss"));
knownPatterns.add(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX"));

for (SimpleDateFormat pattern : knownPatterns) {
    try {
        // Take a try
        return new Date(pattern.parse(candidate).getTime());

    } catch (ParseException pe) {
        // Loop on
    }
}
System.err.println("No known Date format found: " + candidate);
return null;
```

Comment: hey i'm trying look at all these pattersn `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"` can you please point me out to a example or docs of these patterns @xybrek

Comment: Awesome solution. Thanks a ton for sharing.!

Answer (score 17):

Matt's approach above is fine, but please be aware that you will run into problems if you use it to differentiate between dates of the format `y/M/d` and `d/M/y`. For instance, a formatter initialised with `y/M/d` will accept a date like `01/01/2009` and give you back a date which is clearly not what you wanted. I fixed the issue as follows, but I have limited time and I'm not happy with the solution for 2 main reasons:

1. It violates one of Josh Bloch's quidelines, specifically 'don't use exceptions to handle program flow'.
2. I can see the `getDateFormat()` method becoming a bit of a nightmare if you needed it to handle lots of other date formats.

If I had to make something that could handle lots and lots of different date formats and needed to be highly performant, then I think I would use the approach of creating an enum which linked each different date regex to its format. Then use `MyEnum.values()` to loop through the enum and test with `if(myEnum.getPattern().matches(date))` rather than catching a dateformatexception.

Anway, that being said, the following can handle dates of the formats `'y/M/d' 'y-M-d' 'y M d' 'd/M/y' 'd-M-y' 'd M y'` and all other variations of those which include time formats as well:

```java
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateUtil {
    private static final String[] timeFormats = {"HH:mm:ss","HH:mm"};
    private static final String[] dateSeparators = {"/","-"," "};

    private static final String DMY_FORMAT = "dd{sep}MM{sep}yyyy";
    private static final String YMD_FORMAT = "yyyy{sep}MM{sep}dd";

    private static final String ymd_template = "\\d{4}{sep}\\d{2}{sep}\\d{2}.*";
    private static final String dmy_template = "\\d{2}{sep}\\d{2}{sep}\\d{4}.*";

    public static Date stringToDate(String input){
    Date date = null;
    String dateFormat = getDateFormat(input);
    if(dateFormat == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Date is not in an accepted format " + input);
    }

    for(String sep : dateSeparators){
        String actualDateFormat = patternForSeparator(dateFormat, sep);
        //try first with the time
        for(String time : timeFormats){
        date = tryParse(input,actualDateFormat + " " + time);
        if(date != null){
            return date;
        }
        }
        //didn't work, try without the time formats
        date = tryParse(input,actualDateFormat);
        if(date != null){
        return date;
        }
    }

    return date;
    }

    private static String getDateFormat(String date){
    for(String sep : dateSeparators){
        String ymdPattern = patternForSeparator(ymd_template, sep);
        String dmyPattern = patternForSeparator(dmy_template, sep);
        if(date.matches(ymdPattern)){
        return YMD_FORMAT;
        }
        if(date.matches(dmyPattern)){
        return DMY_FORMAT;
        }
    }
    return null;
    }

    private static String patternForSeparator(String template, String sep){
    return template.replace("{sep}", sep);
    }

    private static Date tryParse(String input, String pattern){
    try{
        return new SimpleDateFormat(pattern).parse(input);
    }
    catch (ParseException e) {}
    return null;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 12):

If working in Java 1.8 you can leverage the DateTimeFormatterBuilder

```
public static boolean isTimeStampValid(String inputString)
{
    DateTimeFormatterBuilder dateTimeFormatterBuilder = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .append(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("" + "[yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ]" + "[yyyy-MM-dd]"));

    DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = dateTimeFormatterBuilder.toFormatter();

    try {
        dateTimeFormatter.parse(inputString);
        return true;
    } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

See post: [Java 8 Date equivalent to Joda's DateTimeFormatterBuilder with multiple parser formats?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36188428/java-8-date-equivalent-to-jodas-datetimeformatterbuilder-with-multiple-parser-f)

Comment: Best answer and most dynamic option i've seen so far, thank you

Answer (score 10):

In Apache commons lang, [DateUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/DateUtils.html) class we have a method called parseDate. We can use this for parsing the date.

Also another library Joda-time also have the method to [parse](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html#Formatters) the date.

Answer (score 9):

**Best and Simple Java 8 answer**  (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/59546290/2131040)

```
final DateTimeFormatterBuilder dtfb = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder();
dtfb.appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS"))
.appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSS"))
.appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS"))
.appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"))
.appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSS"))
.appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSS"))
    .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"))
    .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SS"))
    .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S"))
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 0)
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 0);
```

Comment: exactly what I needed, Thanks !!

Comment: This worked for me but looks like the order of adding the formatters matters somehow. I needed to handle `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS` and `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S` but it was failing if I specify the pattern with one millisecond character first. If I put the pattern with three millisecond characters first, both formats are handled correctly.

Answer (score 8):

Here is the complete example (with main method) which can be added as a utility class in your project. All the format mentioned in [SimpleDateFormate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) API is supported in the below method.

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils;

public class DateUtility {

    public static Date parseDate(String inputDate) {

        Date outputDate = null;
        String[] possibleDateFormats =
              {
                    "yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z",
                    "EEE, MMM d, ''yy",
                    "h:mm a",
                    "hh 'o''clock' a, zzzz",
                    "K:mm a, z",
                    "yyyyy.MMMMM.dd GGG hh:mm aaa",
                    "EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z",
                    "yyMMddHHmmssZ",
                    "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ",
                    "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX",
                    "YYYY-'W'ww-u",
                    "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z", 
                    "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm zzzz",
                    "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ",
                    "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSzzzz", 
                    "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszzzz",
                    "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss z",
                    "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz", 
                    "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss",
                    "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HHmmss.SSSz",
                    "yyyy-MM-dd",
                    "yyyyMMdd",
                    "dd/MM/yy",
                    "dd/MM/yyyy"
              };

        try {

            outputDate = DateUtils.parseDate(inputDate, possibleDateFormats);
            System.out.println("inputDate ==> " + inputDate + ", outputDate ==> " + outputDate);

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return outputDate;

    }

    public static String formatDate(Date date, String requiredDateFormat) {
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(requiredDateFormat);
        String outputDateFormatted = df.format(date);
        return outputDateFormatted;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DateUtility.parseDate("20181118");
        DateUtility.parseDate("2018-11-18");
        DateUtility.parseDate("18/11/18");
        DateUtility.parseDate("18/11/2018");
        DateUtility.parseDate("2018.11.18 AD at 12:08:56 PDT");
        System.out.println("");
        DateUtility.parseDate("Wed, Nov 18, '18");
        DateUtility.parseDate("12:08 PM");
        DateUtility.parseDate("12 o'clock PM, Pacific Daylight Time");
        DateUtility.parseDate("0:08 PM, PDT");
        DateUtility.parseDate("02018.Nov.18 AD 12:08 PM");
        System.out.println("");
        DateUtility.parseDate("Wed, 18 Nov 2018 12:08:56 -0700");
        DateUtility.parseDate("181118120856-0700");
        DateUtility.parseDate("2018-11-18T12:08:56.235-0700");
        DateUtility.parseDate("2018-11-18T12:08:56.235-07:00");
        DateUtility.parseDate("2018-W27-3");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

This solution checks all the possible formats before throwing an exception. This solution is more convenient if you are trying to test for multiple date formats.

```
Date extractTimestampInput(String strDate){
    final List<String> dateFormats = Arrays.asList("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS", "yyyy-MM-dd");    

    for(String format: dateFormats){
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        try{
            return sdf.parse(strDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
             //intentionally empty
        }
    }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid input for date. Given '"+strDate+"', expecting format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS or yyyy-MM-dd.");

}
```

Answer (score 2):

For the modern answer I am ignoring the requirement to use `SimpleDateFormat`. While using this class for parsing was a good idea in 2010 when this question was asked, it is now long outdated. The replacement, `DateTimeFormatter`, came out in 2014. The idea in the following is pretty much the same as in the accepted answer.

```
private static DateTimeFormatter[] parseFormatters = Stream.of("M/yy", "M/y", "M/d/y", "M-d-y")
        .map(DateTimeFormatter::ofPattern)
        .toArray(DateTimeFormatter[]::new);

public static YearMonth parseYearMonth(String input) {
    for (DateTimeFormatter formatter : parseFormatters) {
        try {
            return YearMonth.parse(input, formatter);
        } catch (DateTimeParseException dtpe) {
            // ignore, try next format
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not parse " + input);
}
```

This parses each of the input strings from the question into a year-month of `2009-09`. It’s important to try the two-digit year first since `"M/y"` could also parse `9/09`, but into `0009-09` instead.

A limitation of the above code is it ignores the day-of-month from the strings that have one, like `9/1/2009`. Maybe it’s OK as long as most formats have only month and year. To pick it up, we’d have to try `LocalDate.parse()` rather then `YearMonth.parse()` for the formats that include `d` in the pattern string. Surely it can be done.

Answer (score 2):

I'm solved this problem more simple way using regex

```
fun parseTime(time: String?): Long {
    val longRegex = "\\d{4}+-\\d{2}+-\\d{2}+\\w\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}.\\d{3}[Z]\$"
    val shortRegex = "\\d{4}+-\\d{2}+-\\d{2}+\\w\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}Z\$"

    val longDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sssXXX")
    val shortDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX")

    return when {
        Pattern.matches(longRegex, time) -> longDateFormat.parse(time).time
        Pattern.matches(shortRegex, time) -> shortDateFormat.parse(time).time
        else -> throw InvalidParamsException(INVALID_TIME_MESSAGE, null)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implemented the same in scala, Please help urself with converting to Java, the core logic and functions used stays the same.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils

object MultiDataFormat {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

val dates =Array("2015-10-31","26/12/2015","19-10-2016")

val possibleDateFormats:Array[String] = Array("yyyy-MM-dd","dd/MM/yyyy","dd-MM-yyyy")

val sdf =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd") //change it as per the requirement
  for (date<-dates) {
    val outputDate = DateUtils.parseDateStrictly(date, possibleDateFormats)
    System.out.println("inputDate ==> " + date + ", outputDate ==> " +outputDate + " " + sdf.format(outputDate) )
  }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Using DateTimeFormatter it can be achieved as below:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class DateTimeFormatTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String pattern = "[yyyy-MM-dd[['T'][ ]HH:mm:ss[.SSSSSSSz][.SSS[XXX][X]]]]";
        String timeSample = "2018-05-04T13:49:01.7047141Z";
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss");
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern);
        TemporalAccessor accessor = formatter.parse(timeSample);
        ZonedDateTime zTime = LocalDateTime.from(accessor).atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);

        Date date=new Date(zTime.toEpochSecond()*1000);
        simpleDateFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneOffset.UTC));
        System.out.println(simpleDateFormatter.format(date));       
    }
}
```

Pay attention at `String pattern`, this is the combination of multiple patterns. In open `[` and close `]` square brackets you can mention any kind of patterns.

Comment: When you can use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, there is no reason why you should also want to use the poorly designed and long outdated `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date` and `TimeZone`. Mixing old and modern just causes added complexity and confusion.

Comment: also worth mentioning for android developers developing for DateFormatter & ZonedDateTime to work you need your app running on version > 26

Answer (score 0):

I was having multiple date formats into json, and was extracting csv with universal format. I looked multiple places, tried different ways, but at the end I'm able to convert with the following simple code.

```
private String getDate(String anyDateFormattedString) {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Date date = new Date(anyDateFormattedString);
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(yourDesiredDateFormat);
        String convertedDate = dateFormat.format(date);
    return convertedDate;
}
```

Comment: I get `IllegalArgumentException` when trying it with the first sample from the question, `9/09`. Also the constructor you are using was deprecated for a reason, it works unreliably across time zones, so we shouldn’t use it.

Comment: `Date date = new Date(anyDateFormattedString);` this offloads the date parsing to Java. It would probably not give your desired results. e.g. it may treat "03-02-2020" as 3rd Feb or 2nd Mar, you wont know it.