# Parsing a Date given in unknown format to standard format in java?

Tags: java

hi im parsing a csv file with date(custom format),
i have to parse the date given in anyformat(mm-dd-yyyy, yyyy/mm/dd , mmm dd yyyy) to a standard format dd/mm/yyyy.

**The question is how can we find the format in which the date is given?**

is there anyway to do it?

ps: i thinking of asking for the dateformat in the csv.

Comment: Are you aware of [this](http://www.docjar.org/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) ?

Comment: This answer should help you too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4024604/1343161

Answer (score 2):

In your case, the string should contain just one of either  "-" or "/" or " ", so you can dispatch based on that.

Comment: @Thila , i dont know the format given in csv , it can be of anyformat available.

Comment: Be careful on using a list of patterns. It could mean different than what you will interpret. ex. 1/2/3 - It's going to be pure luck and no logic with this approach.

Comment: Any format available? That's not going to work well. For starters, it's ambiguous.