# input date in two different formats. How to parse it

Tags: java, struts-1

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse dates in multiple formats using SimpleDateFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024544/how-to-parse-dates-in-multiple-formats-using-simpledateformat)

I'm using   a  to get input date. The date string can be in two different formats - MM/dd/yyy and dd.MM.yyyy. After submitting I need to parse this string into sql.Date and set it as a property of the nested object in ActionForm. What is the best way to parse this string in different formats and where should it happen?

Comment: What are you using to input the dates ? And for the where should it happen part , the code/overall structure on which you are working would be required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check whether the string contains a "." or a "/" and then apply the appropriate `DateFormat`.

```
static Date parseDate(String in) throws ParseException {
  return new SimpleDateFormat(in.contains(".")? "dd.MM.yyyy" : "MM/dd/yyyy")
    .parse(in);
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  System.out.println(parseDate("31.01.2001"));
  System.out.println(parseDate("01/31/2001"));
}
```