# how do i format date that i get from user as input and then find that date in a calendar to find out which day_of_month is it in that calendar?

Tags: java, date, format

im getting a date including (`-` or `/` or space) in a format `dd-mm-yyyy` or `dd.MMM.yy` for example

`dd.MM.yyyy`
`dd-MM-yy`
`dd MM yyyy`

how to get this to my format `dd MM yyyy` even if the user put last two digit for the year I have to convert it to 4 digit number?

Comment: This is a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024544/how-to-parse-dates-in-multiple-formats-using-simpledateformat

Answer (score 0):

So you are wanting:

replace all / with space
replace all - with space
replace after last space with 4 digits  assume this century 13 -> 2013

Then use SimpleDateFormat.parse

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) [DateUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/DateUtils.html) which allows you to parse a date `String` using a series of different date patterns.

The simple uses the [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to do the actual work, but makes it easier when you want to try using multiple formats rather then having to loop it self.

Once you have it back to `Date` value, you can use `SimpleDateFormat` to format the `Date` just about anyway you want it

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your date: ");
    String[] format={"dd.MM.yyyy", "dd-MM-yy","dd MM yyyy"};
        for (String i : format)
        {
            try
            {
                Date date=new SimpleDateFormat(i).parse(sc.nextLine());
                System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy").format(date) );
            }
            catch (ParseException e) {

            }
        }
```

Live Demo [here](http://ideone.com/ZMKEXW).

You can add what ever the `SimpleDateFormat` to `format` `array`. Then this will convert to `"dd MM yyyy"` format.

Comment: i need a lil bit more help how do i compare this date with the calendar so i will able to get the day_of_week and also how do i calculate leap year in the calendar?