# Java dateformatter

Tags: java, simpledateformat

Is there an easy way to parse the following 2 types of String to Date in Java

```
2013-11-22T18:37:55.645+0000
2013-11-22T14:20:30.645Z
```

Both mean the same thing, but I am having to use 2 different date format patterns

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'
```

and I want to do it with only 1 pattern.

Comment: You could use the first, and just call `String.replace("Z", "+0000")` on your input Strings couldn't you?

Comment: Yes, I could do that, but I would rather not do that if that is avoidable

Comment: Maybe you could subclass [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024544/how-to-parse-dates-in-multiple-formats-using-simpledateformat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your format patterns are variations of the same, [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Easy in [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3.

One line of code, using Joda-Time's built-in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formatter. That formatter handles both offsets, either zeros or a `Z`.

```java
org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime().withZoneUTC().parseDateTime( eitherStringGoesHere );
```

More detailed code…

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.

String dateTimeStringZero = "2013-11-22T18:37:55.645+0000";
String dateTimeStringZulu = "2013-11-22T18:37:55.645Z";

org.joda.time.DateTime dateTimeZero = org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime().withZoneUTC().parseDateTime( dateTimeStringZero );
org.joda.time.DateTime dateTimeZulu = org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime().withZoneUTC().parseDateTime( dateTimeStringZulu );
```

Output…

```java
System.out.println( "dateTimeZero: " + dateTimeZero );
System.out.println( "dateTimeZulu: " + dateTimeZulu );
```

When run…

```
dateTimeZero: 2013-11-22T18:37:55.645Z
dateTimeZulu: 2013-11-22T18:37:55.645Z
```

---

If you want a time zoned DateTime, change out the `withZoneUTC()`. See the [`withZone`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withZone%28org.joda.time.DateTimeZone%29) method. For user’s default time zone, simply omit any time zone call.

Comment: This looks exactly what I wanted.. Unfortunately it means I need to bring in joda jar file. I thought I could do without it, but there seems no way.

Comment: @Harsha Joda-Time is the first thing I add to a new project (even before [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/) & [LogBack](http://logback.qos.ch/)). Unfortunately, the java.util.Date/Calendar classes bundled with Java are notoriously bad, the worst part of the Java platform. That's why they are being supplanted by [JSR 310: Date and Time API](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) (java.time.*) in Java 8. JSR 310 is inspired by Joda-Time, but entirely re-architected, not directly built on Joda-Time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a very simple way called `SimpleDateFormat`. Send your format to constructor of this class and format date according to your spec.

Comment: Of course SimpleDateFormat, but I would have to call it 2 times with the 2 formats. I wanted a single format which could match both patterns

Comment: Unfortunatly `SimpleDateFormat` does not support such option. It seems that you offer here an idea of `PatternDateFormat` that accepts patterns and therefore can match several formats. You are welcome to implement such one. It sounds interesting and pretty useful!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    Date dt1 = sdf.parse(str1);
```