# Java date parsing with microsecond or nanosecond accuracy

Tags: java, simpledateformat, milliseconds

According to the [SimpleDateFormat class documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), `Java` does not support time granularity above milliseconds in its date patterns.

So, a date string like

- 2015-05-09 00:10:23.999750900 // The last 9 digits denote nanoseconds

when parsed via the pattern

- yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS // 9 'S' symbols

actually interprets the whole number after the `.` symbol as (nearly 1 billion!) milliseconds and not as nanoseconds, resulting in the date

- 2015-05-20 21:52:53 UTC

i.e. over 11 days ahead. Surprisingly, using a smaller number of `S` symbols still results in all 9 digits being parsed (instead of, say, the leftmost 3 for `.SSS`).

There are 2 ways to handle this issue correctly:

- Use string preprocessing
- Use a custom SimpleDateFormat implementation

Would there be any other way for getting a correct solution by just supplying a pattern to the standard `SimpleDateFormat` implementation, without any other code modifications or string manipulation?

Comment: *... by just supplying a pattern to the standard `SimpleDateFormat` implementation, without any other code modifications or string manipulation?* Obviously not.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDateTime.parse(                 // With resolution of nanoseconds, represent the idea of a date and time somewhere, unspecified. Does *not* represent a moment, is *not* a point on the timeline. To determine an actual moment, place this date+time into context of a time zone (apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`). 
    "2015-05-09 00:10:23.999750900"  // A `String` nearly in standard ISO 8601 format.
    .replace( " " , "T" )            // Replace SPACE in middle with `T` to comply with ISO 8601 standard format.
)                                    // Returns a `LocalDateTime` object.
```

## Nope

No, you cannot use SimpleDateFormat to handle [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond).

But your premise that…

> Java does not support time granularity above [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millsecond) in its date patterns

…is no longer true as of [Java 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8_.28March_18.2C_2014.29), 9, 10 and later with *java.time* classes built-in. And not really true of Java 6 and Java 7 either, as most of the *java.time* [functionality is back-ported](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).

## java.time

`SimpleDateFormat`, and the related `java.util.Date`/`.Calendar` classes are now outmoded by the new [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) package found in Java 8 ([Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)).

The new java.time classes support [nanosecond](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) resolution. That support includes parsing and generating nine digits of fractional second.  For example, when you use the `java.time.format` `DateTimeFormatter` API, the `S` pattern letter denotes a "fraction of the second" rather than "milliseconds", and it can cope with nanosecond values.

### `Instant`

As an example, the [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). Its `toString` method generates a `String` object using the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. The `Z` on the end means UTC, pronounced “Zulu”.

```
instant.toString()  // Generate a `String` representing this moment, using standard ISO 8601 format.
```

> 2013-08-20T12:34:56.123456789Z

Note that capturing the current moment in Java 8 is limited to millisecond resolution. The *java.time* classes can *hold* a value in nanoseconds, but can only determine the current time with milliseconds. This limitation is due to the implementation of `Clock`. In Java 9 and later, a new `Clock` implementation can grab the current moment in finer resolution, depending on the limits of your host hardware and operating system, usually [microseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond) in my experience.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture the current moment. May be in milliseconds or microseconds rather than the maximum resolution of nanoseconds.
```

### `LocalDateTime`

Your example input string of `2015-05-09 00:10:23.999750900` lacks an indicator of time zone or offset-from-UTC. That means it does *not* represent a moment, is *not* a point on the timeline. Instead, it represents *potential* moments along a range of about 26-27 hours, the range of time zones around the globe.

Pares such an input as a `LocalDateTime` object. First, replace the SPACE in the middle with a `T` to comply with ISO 8601 format, used by default when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = 
        LocalDateTime.parse( 
            "2015-05-09 00:10:23.999750900".replace( " " , "T" )  // Replace SPACE in middle with `T` to comply with ISO 8601 standard format.
        ) 
;
```

## `java.sql.Timestamp`

The [`java.sql.Timestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) class also handles nanosecond resolution, but in an awkward way. Generally best to do your work inside java.time classes. No need to ever use `Timestamp` again as of JDBC 4.2 and later.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , instant ) ;
```

And retrieval.

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class ) ;
```

### `OffsetDateTime`

Support for `Instant` is not mandated by the JDBC specification, but `OffsetDateTime` is. So if the above code fails with your JDBC driver, use the following.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ; 
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

And retrieval.

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ).toInstant() ;
```

If using an older pre-4.2 JDBC driver, you can use [`toInstant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#toInstant--) and [`from`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#from-java.time.Instant-) methods to go back and forth between `java.sql.Timestamp` and java.time. These new conversion methods were added to the *old* legacy classes.

[image: Table of date-time types in Java (both legacy and modern) and in standard SQL]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Yes, although the requirement was for a `SimpleDateFormat` solution, due to the corresponding use case.

Comment: @OleV.V. Done. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Anyone looking to parse a datetime string with timezone in it, you can use instant.Parse("datetimestring")

Comment: @PrashantSaraswat No, for a time zone, use `ZonedDateTime`, not `Instant`. See my table graphic in my Answer.

Comment: @BasilBourque Thanks for pointing this out. Both work. I used instant because thats what the javadoc for LocalDateTime suggested.

Answer (score 16):

I found the it wonderful to cover multiple variants of date time format like this:

```
final DateTimeFormatterBuilder dtfb = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder();
dtfb.appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS"))
.appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSS"))
.appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS"))
.appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"))
.appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSS"))
.appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSS"))
    .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"))
    .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SS"))
    .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S"))
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 0)
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 0);
```

Comment: Thank you for this!!! Spent quite some time looking at various more complicated solutions for handling variable input and this was exactly what worked!

Answer (score 2):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html).

You can build a `DateTimeFormatter` using `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` as shown below:

```
DateTimeFormatter parser = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
        .appendLiteral(' ')
        .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
        .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

**Demo**:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateTimeFormatter parser = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
        .appendLiteral(' ')
        .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
        .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);

    // Test
    Stream.of(
        "2015-05-09 00:10:23.123456789",
        "2015-05-09 00:10:23.12345678",
        "2015-05-09 00:10:23.1234567",
        "2015-05-09 00:10:23.123456",
        "2015-05-09 00:10:23.12345",
        "2015-05-09 00:10:23.1234",
        "2015-05-09 00:10:23.123",
        "2015-05-09 00:10:23.12",
        "2015-05-09 00:10:23.1",
        "2015-05-09 00:10:23.1",
        "2015-05-09 00:10:23",
        "2015-05-09 00:10"
      )
      .map(s -> LocalDateTime.parse(s, parser))
      .forEach(System.out::println);
  }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2015-05-09T00:10:23.123456789
2015-05-09T00:10:23.123456780
2015-05-09T00:10:23.123456700
2015-05-09T00:10:23.123456
2015-05-09T00:10:23.123450
2015-05-09T00:10:23.123400
2015-05-09T00:10:23.123
2015-05-09T00:10:23.120
2015-05-09T00:10:23.100
2015-05-09T00:10:23.100
2015-05-09T00:10:23
2015-05-09T00:10
```

If you want to make the time part optional, you can use the following `DateTimeFormatter`:

```
DateTimeFormatter parser = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
    .optionalStart()
    .appendLiteral(' ')
    .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
    .optionalEnd()
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
    .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

**Demo**:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateTimeFormatter parser = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
        .optionalStart()
        .appendLiteral(' ')
        .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
        .optionalEnd()
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
        .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);

    // Test
    Stream.of(
        "2015-05-09 00:10:23.123456789",
        "2015-05-09 00:10:23.12345678",
        "2015-05-09 00:10:23.1234567",
        "2015-05-09 00:10:23.123456",
        "2015-05-09 00:10:23.12345",
        "2015-05-09 00:10:23.1234",
        "2015-05-09 00:10:23.123",
        "2015-05-09 00:10:23.12",
        "2015-05-09 00:10:23.1",
        "2015-05-09 00:10:23.1",
        "2015-05-09 00:10:23",
        "2015-05-09 00:10",
        "2015-05-09"
        )
        .map(s -> LocalDateTime.parse(s, parser))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
  }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2015-05-09T00:10:23.123456789
2015-05-09T00:10:23.123456780
2015-05-09T00:10:23.123456700
2015-05-09T00:10:23.123456
2015-05-09T00:10:23.123450
2015-05-09T00:10:23.123400
2015-05-09T00:10:23.123
2015-05-09T00:10:23.120
2015-05-09T00:10:23.100
2015-05-09T00:10:23.100
2015-05-09T00:10:23
2015-05-09T00:10
2015-05-09T00:00
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Answer (score 2):

TEST CODE:

```
@Test
void contextLoads() throws ParseException {
    DateTimeFormatter ISO_LOCAL_DATE = new >DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendValue(YEAR, 4, 10, SignStyle.EXCEEDS_PAD)
            .optionalStart().appendLiteral('/').optionalEnd()
            .optionalStart().appendLiteral('-').optionalEnd()
            .optionalStart().appendValue(MONTH_OF_YEAR, 2)
            .optionalStart().appendLiteral('/').optionalEnd()
            .optionalStart().appendLiteral('-').optionalEnd()
            .optionalStart().appendValue(DAY_OF_MONTH, 2)
            .toFormatter();

    DateTimeFormatter ISO_LOCAL_TIME = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendValue(HOUR_OF_DAY, 2)
            .optionalStart().appendLiteral(':').appendValue(MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 2)
            .optionalStart().appendLiteral(':').appendValue(SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 2)
            .optionalStart().appendFraction(NANO_OF_SECOND, 0, 9, true)
            .optionalStart().appendZoneId()
            .toFormatter();

    DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .append(ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
            .optionalStart().appendLiteral(' ').optionalEnd()
            .optionalStart().appendLiteral('T').optionalEnd()
            .optionalStart().appendOptional(ISO_LOCAL_TIME).optionalEnd()
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 0)
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 0)
            .toFormatter(Locale.SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE);

    Stream.of("2015-05-09T00:10:23.934596635Z",
            "2015-05-09 00:10:23.123456789UTC",
            "2015/05/09 00:10:23.123456789",
            "2015-05-09 00:10:23.12345678",
            "2015/05/09 00:10:23.1234567",
            "2015-05-09T00:10:23.123456",
            "2015-05-09 00:10:23.12345",
            "2015/05-09T00:10:23.1234",
            "2015-05-09 00:10:23.123",
            "2015-05-09 00:10:23.12",
            "2015-05-09 00:10:23.1",
            "2015-05-09 00:10:23",
            "2015-05-09 00:10",
            "2015-05-09 01",
            "2015-05-09"
    ).forEach(s -> {
        LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse(s, dateTimeFormatter);
        System.out.println(s + " ==> " + date);
    });
}
```

OUT:

```
2015-05-09T00:10:23.934596635Z ==> 2015-05-09T00:10:23.934596635
2015-05-09 00:10:23.123456789UTC ==> 2015-05-09T00:10:23.123456789
2015/05/09 00:10:23.123456789 ==> 2015-05-09T00:10:23.123456789
2015-05-09 00:10:23.12345678 ==> 2015-05-09T00:10:23.123456780
2015/05/09 00:10:23.1234567 ==> 2015-05-09T00:10:23.123456700
2015-05-09T00:10:23.123456 ==> 2015-05-09T00:10:23.123456
2015-05-09 00:10:23.12345 ==> 2015-05-09T00:10:23.123450
2015/05-09T00:10:23.1234 ==> 2015-05-09T00:10:23.123400
2015-05-09 00:10:23.123 ==> 2015-05-09T00:10:23.123
2015-05-09 00:10:23.12 ==> 2015-05-09T00:10:23.120
2015-05-09 00:10:23.1 ==> 2015-05-09T00:10:23.100
2015-05-09 00:10:23 ==> 2015-05-09T00:10:23
2015-05-09 00:10 ==> 2015-05-09T00:10
2015-05-09 01 ==> 2015-05-09T01:00
2015-05-09 ==> 2015-05-09T00:00
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).