# Android parse date issue

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

I'm receiving really strange date format from server. It looks **2017-03-07T15:08:01.513544Z** , and strange part is six last characters before "Z", because I've seen only three symbols of milliseconds in the most responses from servers. I'm trying to parse it with `SimpleDateFormat` with the mask **yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'**, and it works on all android versions except **api 16 (4.1)**. In *developer.android.com* I saw example with the mask like .SSSXXX, but as result I have error, because system doesn't know symbol 'X'. **So, have you ever faced with similar date format?**

Comment: Could you [edit] your question? You can improve formatting and adjust the question to [mcve] and [ask]

Comment: this type of date format will be in Calendar like Outlook invitation

Comment: "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmm'00'" I have used like this

Comment: Mostly correct, @tommus. Java 8 has nanosecond precision, so not a microsecond will be lost.

Comment: The IBM mainframe I was working with, used to give us time stamps with 6 decimals on the seconds like yours. The format you mention conforms with ISO 8601, so there should be plenty of options for parsing it.

Comment: See also [Java date parsing with microsecond or nanosecond accuracy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30135025/java-date-parsing-with-microsecond-or-nanosecond-accuracy) and [java.util.Date format SSSSSS: if not microseconds what are the last 3 digits?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19223171/java-util-date-format-ssssss-if-not-microseconds-what-are-the-last-3-digits)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is straightforward but entails a little more than just the answer.

```
    Instant instantFromServer = Instant.parse("2017-03-07T15:08:01.513544Z");
```

To use this on Android you will need to get the ThreeTenABP library. It contains the date and time classes described in JSR-310 of which `Instant` is one. See the links below.

> **So, have you ever faced with similar date format?**

`01.513544` means 1.513544 seconds, or 1 second 513 milliseconds 544 microseconds, or 1 second 513544000 nanoseconds. There are many ways to put it. I have worked with IBM mainframes that routinely gave us timestamps with microsecond precision, that is, 6 decimals on the seconds. I suppose as computers are getting faster, accuracy requirements are getting stricter, so we may see more of these in the future. While I believe that `SimpleDateFormat` cannot handle these, the classes in JSR-310 generally have nanosecond precision and parse strings with variable number of decimals out of the box.

### Links

- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP)
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project)