# Parse nano seconds with less than 6 digits

Tags: java, java-time, datetime-parsing

I have the Timestamp `2017-07-25 16:19:59.89384`

I want to parse it with:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");
LocalDate time = LocalDateTime.parse(timeStamp, formatter);
```

But I get a `DateTimeParseException` because the nano seconds are only 5 digits.  Is there a cleaner solution than padding `0`'s to the right?

Comment: suppose this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30135025/java-date-parsing-with-microsecond-or-nanosecond-accuracy) may be helpful to you find a formatter for displaly nano seconds.

Comment: I believe one option is `timeStamp = timeStamp.replace(' ', 'T');` and then use the one-arg `LocalDateTime.parse(CharSequence)`. Personally I prefer [Hugo’s solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45315209/5772882), but it’s much a matter of taste.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the input **always** has 5 digits in nanoseconds, you can use five `S` letters instead of six:

```
String timeStamp = "2017-07-25 16:19:59.89384";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSS"); // five "S"
LocalDateTime datetime = LocalDateTime.parse(timeStamp, formatter);
```

Also note that `LocalDateTime.parse` returns a `LocalDateTime` (not a `LocalDate` like in your code).

---

If you don't know how many digits will be in the input, you can use a `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder` with a `java.time.temporal.ChronoField` and define the minimum and maximum number of digits:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // date / time
    .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    // nanoseconds, with minimum 1 and maximum 9 digits and a decimal point
    .appendFraction(ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND, 1, 9, true)
    // create formatter
    .toFormatter();
LocalDateTime datetime = LocalDateTime.parse(timeStamp, formatter);
```

You just need to adjust the values 1 and 9 according to your needs.

Answer (score 3):

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.n");
```

Comment: Hello @SChristy. Please add an explanation to the answer to make it more useful. As it is now it's being flagged as low quality.

Comment: Nothing worked except your solution, my friend. Live long and prosper :D