# scala - parsing milliseconds time data

Tags: scala

I tried to parsing time string to time data, But having problem to parsing millisecond part. Anyone know how to do this?

```
   val format = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd aa hh:mm:ss.SSSSSS")
    format.setLenient( false)

    Try(new Timestamp(format.parse( "2015-11-13 6:27:26.933000").getTime)) match {
        case Success(t) => Some(t)
        case Failure(_) =>
            // cannot convert. error here
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java date parsing with microsecond or nanosecond accuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30135025/java-date-parsing-with-microsecond-or-nanosecond-accuracy)

Answer (score 2):

- You use `aa` but don't provide it in the actual input, what causes a failure
- `S` stands for milliseconds, and it ranges between 0 and 999, and you provided a bigger number, what causes a failure
- you asked for `hh`, but gave in the input a single digit, but it doesn't cause a failure.

And working example:

```
val format = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd a hh:mm:ss.SSS")
format.setLenient( false)

Try(new Timestamp(format.parse("2015-11-13 PM 06:27:26.933").getTime)) match {
  case Success(t) => println(t.getTime)
  case Failure(err) => println(err)
}
```

Comment: My timedata has 6 digit of milliseconds. It's my main problem.

Comment: for example, 2015-11-13 PM 06:27:26.933000

Comment: Then look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30135025/java-date-parsing-with-microsecond-or-nanosecond-accuracy