# Java Timestamp Format Conversion

Tags: java

I have a Timestamp format in a string attribute .When I format it is adding some extra minutes i can see deviation in minutes.
Have any one faced.Please help me out here

```
String dddddd="2017-11-29 09:24:03.857921";
SimpleDateFormat  fullMonthFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");
SimpleDateFormat  fullMonthFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");
Date strd11;
strd11=fullMonthFormat1.parse(dddddd);
System.out.println("chec date"+strd11);

String aa=fullMonthFormat2.format(strd11);
System.out.println("aa date"+aa);

o/p
chec dateWed Nov 29 09:38:20 IST 2017
aa date29-Nov-2017 09:38:20.000921
```

Comment: Seems somewhat similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30135025/java-date-parsing-with-microsecond-or-nanosecond-accuracy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem are your milliseconds, 857921 milliseconds are equal to ~ 14 minutes (14,2986833), which seems to be the time that got added to your output (output is correct, your input String or pattern needs fixing if you dont want this behaviour)

Comment: Tx  is there anything i can do without touching the source string .

Comment: @VikramSrinivasan: See my other answer regarding `LocalDateTime`.

Answer (score 2):

TestingTest's answers your question already. Yet, if you want a different behaviour which does not re-calculate the minute you could use `java.time.LocalDateTime` (you need Java 8 though). This class does not mess up the minutes like `SimpleDateformat`.

See the difference in the code snippet below:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Date;

public class TimeChecks {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String dddddd = "2017-11-29 09:24:03.857921";
        SimpleDateFormat fullMonthFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");
        SimpleDateFormat fullMonthFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");
        Date strd11;
        strd11 = fullMonthFormat1.parse(dddddd);
        System.out.println("chec date" + strd11);

        String aa = fullMonthFormat2.format(strd11);
        System.out.println("aa date" + aa);

        LocalDateTime localDate = LocalDateTime.parse(dddddd, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"));
        System.out.printf("Local date: %s%n", localDate);
    }
}
```

This prints out:

```
chec dateWed Nov 29 09:38:20 GMT 2017
aa date29-Nov-2017 09:38:20.000921
Local date: 2017-11-29T09:24:03.857921
```

As you can see local date time does not change the minutes - it keeps the milliseconds as is.