# Coldfusion - odd parsedatetime results

Tags: coldfusion, datetime-format, coldfusion-10

I have a time string:

```
2018-08-09T13:19:22.479522-05:00
```

Parsing the string using:

```
parseDateTime(time, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSXXX")
```

Yields this result:

```
2018-08-09 14:27:21
```

I'm -4 hours from GMT, so I get the hour difference, but why is the minute different?

**Update:** 
I'm certain the problem is the 6 digit millisecond, but can ColdFusion process this? As of now, I'm using `left()` and `right()` to get around the issue.

Comment: Note: Patrick discovered that the problem was related to the 6-digit millisecond in the mask.  I deleted my (wrong) answer, which contained that discussion.

Comment: *can coldfusion process this* Nope.  java.util.Date (which is what CF uses along with SimpleDateFormat) don't support that level of granularity. That's why the time is being misinterpreted. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30135025/java-date-parsing-with-microsecond-or-nanosecond-accuracy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why is the minute different?

It's because [java.util.Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) (which is what ColdFusion uses along with [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)) doesn't handle [microseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond), only milliseconds. The mask `".SSSSSS"` only allows CF/Java to *extract* the extra digits, but once extracted that whole value is treated as a number of milliseconds:

- `479522 milliseconds` ... or
- `479.522 seconds` ... or
- `7 minutes, 59 seconds and 522 milliseconds`

So in this case, instead of adding fractions of a second, it increases the final time by nearly eight minutes. That's why the result isn't quite what you expected.

```
Base Time  14:19:22.000
   +               .522 milliseconds
   +             59.000 seconds
   +           7:00.000 minutes  
   ====================
Final Time 14:27:21.522
```

**tl;dr;**

[ParseDateTime()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-m-r/parsedatetime.html) can't process that particular date/time string, so you'll have to DIY.