# Which date pattern in java can produce this date result? (seven digits after seconds)

Tags: java, date

I need a date pattern to generate date string like this :
2019-12-18T17:11:24.2646051+03:30

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.?XXX").format(new Date())
```

What should I write instead of '?' ?

Comment: The closes I can come to is `S`, which micro seconds, but, this is limited to 3 numeric places.  Nano seconds (`n`) will give 9.  You should also be using `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` and `java.time.ZonedDateTime` instead of the out-dated `java.util.Date` classes

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `OffsetDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First point, get rid of `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Also there is no way that `SimpleDateFormat` can produce 7 decimals on the seconds.

Second point, you probably don’t need to print 7 decimals on the seconds. Your format exemplified through `2019-12-18T17:11:24.2646051+03:30` is ISO 8601. In ISO 8601 the number of decimals on the seconds is free, so everyone should accept if you give them a string with 3 decimals, 9 decimals or no decimals at all (in the last case leave out the decimal point too).

### java.time

So the easy solution is:

```
    String desiredString
            = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toString();
    System.out.println(desiredString);
```

Output when I ran the code just now:

> 2019-12-28T11:46:07.308+01:00

I am using java.time, the modern Java date and time API. And I am exploiting the fact that the `toString` methods of the date and time classes of java.time print ISO 8601 format. So we need no explicit formatter so far.

If you do want or need 7 decimals, do use a `DateTimeFormatter`:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
            .appendLiteral('T')
            .appendPattern("HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSXXX")
            .toFormatter();
    String desiredString = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                                .format(formatter);
```

> 2019-12-28T11:48:52.3840000+01:00

It is possible to specify the formatter using a format pattern string only, but I prefer to reuse the built-in `ISO_LOCAL_DATE` formatter for the date part also when the code gets a few lines longer.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZ").format(new Date())
```

If you want more accuracy than milliseconds please look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30135025/java-date-parsing-with-microsecond-or-nanosecond-accuracy)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `S` for the milliseconds. See [this documentation page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). You cannot use more than 3 though; there seems to be no support for microseconds or more fine-grained options.

```java
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;  
import java.util.Date;  

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX").format(new Date());

    System.out.println(s);
  }
}
```

Example output:

```
2019-12-28T10:28:02.933Z
```

If you do need more granularity, using the `Instant.now()` function might be an option, although the following code will only produce 6 digits (microseconds, no nanoseconds):

```
import java.time.Instant;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Instant.now().toString());
  }
}
```

Example output:

```
2019-12-28T10:31:56.477551Z
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48573980/787036) for more info.

Comment: `SSSSSSS` just give you 4 extra 0's before millisecond.

Comment: Indeed, fixed that, sorry! Seems there is no microsecond option?

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` does not support time granularity above milliseconds in its date patterns.

Comment: The number of decimals printed by `Instant.now().toString()` varies by (1) Java version (2) platform (3) whether you happen to hit a while number of milliseconds, not to mention a whole number of seconds.