# @JsonFormat parse 6 milliseconds digits

Tags: java, json, spring

Is it possible to parse date like 2022-01-20T09:08:42.518925 using @JsonFormat annotation?

`@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS")`
gets me parsing error.

And furthermore can I make milliseconds part optional? Like [.SSSSSS]

Answer (score -1):

I think it's not possible to parse that amount of milliseconds. I leave you a post where they explain it quite well: [Java date parsing with microsecond or nanosecond accuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30135025/java-date-parsing-with-microsecond-or-nanosecond-accuracy)