# How can I format a String to a time in java?

Tags: java, datetime, format

I have a couple of Strings which are times:

fe: value could be:

```
"10:22:27.5528485+05:30"
"11:22:27.552"
"14:22:27"
```

I want to sort these Strings from oldest to latest...
Anyone has an idea?

Thanks

Comment: Parse them into timestamps and sort them in natural order.

Answer (score 0):

As per this [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024544/how-to-parse-dates-in-multiple-formats-using-simpledateformat) SO question, you will have to change those strings into their equivalent date time components and them sort them as dates.