# Parse Logger date time into required format

Tags: java, datetime, simpledateformat

I am working on some application where I need to parse logger stack trace date into required format kindly help me on this..

Date format after parsing logger : [Wed Jul 22 09:29:09 2015]
Required format : yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse dates in multiple formats using SimpleDateFormat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024544/how-to-parse-dates-in-multiple-formats-using-simpledateformat)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SimpleDateFormat loggerFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

Date date = loggerFormat.parse("Wed Jul 22 09:29:09 2015");
String output = targetFormat.format(date); // 2015-07-22 09:29:09
```