# How to convert a string to a Date?

Tags: java

I don't know what format string is

May be `2015-10-10` or `2015/10/10`, may also be `2015-10-30 15:30`

Regular first I want to use to judge whether a valid date or time, and then use the SimpleDateFormat parsing, what should I do better?

All formats include：

```
- yyyy-MM-dd
- yyyy.MM-dd
- yyyy/MM/dd
- yyyy-MM-dd HH24:mm
- yyyy.MM-dd HH24:mm
- yyyy/MM/dd HH24:mm
- yyyy-MM-dd HH24:mm:ss
- yyyy.MM-dd HH24:mm:ss
- yyyy/MM/dd HH24:mm:ss
```

Comment: You'd better have some idea of all the possible formats that might be used. If not, you're in trouble and so is your code,.... and so is this question.

Comment: please refer  http://viralpatel.net/blogs/check-string-is-valid-date-java/ may be it can give you idea.

Comment: thanks, this class can satisfy my needs.

Comment: Thanks for the updated information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [Natty Date Parser](https://github.com/joestelmach/natty) for this. You can try it out [here](http://natty.joestelmach.com/try.jsp). It is available on maven central [here](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.joestelmach%7Cnatty%7C0.12%7Cjar). If you are using gradle:

```
compile 'com.joestelmach:natty:0.12'
```

**Example usage:**

```
String[] exampleDates = {
    "2015-10-10",
    "2015/10/10",
    "2015-10-30 15:30"
};

Parser parser = new Parser();
for (String dateString : exampleDates) {
  List<DateGroup> dates = parser.parse(dateString);
  Date date = dates.get(0).getDates().get(0);
  System.out.println(date);
}
```

**Output:**

> Sat Oct 10 20:51:10 PDT 2015
>
> Sat Oct 10 20:51:10 PDT 2015
>
> Fri Oct 30 15:30:00 PDT 2015

---

**EDIT:**

If you know the date formats then the following StackOverflow would be better than adding a dependency to your project:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4024604/1048340

---

The following static utility method might suffice:

```
/**
 * Parses a date with the given formats. If the date could not be parsed then {@code null} is
 * returned.
 *
 * @param formats the possible date formats
 * @param dateString the date string to parse
 * @return the {@link java.util.Date} or {@code null} if the string could not be parsed.
 */
public static Date getDate(String[] formats, String dateString) {
  for (String format : formats) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
    try {
      return sdf.parse(dateString);
    } catch (ParseException ignored) {
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use following date formatter to convert the date to String.
String d="2015-05-12";
DateFormat formatter  = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
Date a=formatter.parse(d);
```