# Single pattern for java 8 date time

Tags: java, date, parsing, time, java-8

```
public static long convertDateTimeToEpochMillis(String eventDate,String eventTime) {
    String patternMills = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS";           
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern);
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(eventDate + " " + 
    eventTime, dtf);
}
```

This is giving a parsing exception when I am passing `2018-07-19 23:11:52.3` but parses successfully for `2018-07-19 23:11:52.312`. I don't want to specify 3 different patterns for different times like `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S`,`yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SS` and `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS`.

Can I provide a single pattern which will take up to 1/10th of a sec, 100th of a sec and millisec?

Comment: why should you accept the 3 format? i think that you should choose one single format, ideally `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS` and keep that in the whole application

Comment: It gives a DateTimeParseException just as I mentioned above.

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36188428/java-8-date-equivalent-to-jodas-datetimeformatterbuilder-with-multiple-parser-f

Comment: Check the answer at the duplicated tagged question, it looks to be a awesome solution

Comment: You are aware that your code cannot be compiled? When posting a question on Stack Overflow (not about a compiler error message) please make sure it can so we can try your code out, see it fail in the way you describe and try our suggested correction out before we post it. I get “pattern cannot be resolved to a variable” and next “This method must return a result of type long”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just choose a pattern with three SSS as default

```
String patternMills = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS";
```

and fulfill right side of your date with zeros when necessary

```
String eventDate = "2018-07-19 23:11:52.3";
String millis = eventDate.substring(eventDate.lastIndexOf('.')+1);

if(millis.length() < 3) 
    eventDate += Stream.generate(() -> "0").limit(3 - millis.length()).collect(Collectors.joining(""));
```

or use nice apache method:

```
StringUtils.rightPad(eventDate, 23, '0'); // 23 is string length for "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS" pattern
```

Anyway you can also add some validation to check the rest part of the date string

Comment: I don't know this answer is correct but instead of `split` use  `eventDate.substring(eventDate.lastIndexOf(".")+1)`

Comment: @HadiJ actually edited my answer - thx ;)

Comment: Note that the OP have to decide whether the `3` in `2018-07-19 23:11:52.3` means 3 milliseconds or 300 miliseconds, and right or left pad accordingly.

Comment: @nos you are quite not right. 23:11:52.3 is always 300 ms. and 3 milliseconds will be 23:11:52.003

Comment: @Vadim That depend on your input. I've parsed files where the .3 means 300 miliseconds. And even files where the last .3 meant 1/3 of a second.

Comment: @nos - are you kidding? how about Math basics? what milli- stands for in "millisecond"? and 0.3 does never mean 1/3 ... except somebody with no basic math knowledge built that file :-)

Comment: It’s a convoluted solution IMHO (though it should work). I wouldn’t want to end up maintaining this code, and would be likely to rewrite it if I did.

Answer (score 3):

## ISO 8601

Actually your pattern is not far from accepted by [`LocalDateTime.parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence)) default pattern, using standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

So, maybe put not a space but letter `T` instead will be enough for you?

Then you do not need [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) at all.

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(eventDate + "T" + 
eventTime);
```

It accepts any number of digits in milliseconds part, from 0 up to 9.

Comment: ✔ Indeed, I confirmed that `LocalDateTime.parse( "2018-07-19T23:11:52.3" ).toString()` works, yielding `2018-07-19T23:11:52.300` in Java 10.0.1.