# Convert date from YYYY-MM-DD to YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ

Tags: java

I want to convert the following pattern to `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ssz`

```
         2017-feb-02
         2017-05-02
         2017-01-01 03:00:00
         2017-01-01 00:00:00.0
```

I have gone through SimpleDateFormat class of Java. But I coudn't able to achieve it.

Comment: Hope this one helps [Java string to date conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4024604/3042145 And the T Character you need to surround it with '', as GopsAB mentioned

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java string to date conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

Answer (score 1):

The pattern you want to convert it should be like: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz`. See more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).
You can do it with `SimpleDateFormat`, a small example:

```
    String date = "2017-05-02";
    String oldFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    String newFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(oldFormat);
    try {
        Date newDate = sdf.parse(date);
        sdf.applyPattern(newFormat);
        System.out.println(sdf.format(newDate));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Seems interesting. let me try that 'applyPattern'. But how do I solve the other cases. My date string is dynamic. I dont want to have n formats to parse

Comment: @GopsAB, well, you have N formats to parse already, according to your question. Why not have N parsers? These won't make you hard-pressed from memory standpoint or anything.

Comment: @GopsAB, you kind of need to know and have the right or expected formats, else how can you determine which is the month in `2017-05-02` for example? You can easily make an `Enum` with all the formats and use them properly.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve your problem like this, with the help mentioned in the comment section of your question:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {

    String[] formatStrings = { "yyyy-MMM-dd", "yyyy-MM-dd", "yyyy-MMM-dd hh:mm:ss", "yyyy-MMM-dd hh:mm:ss.S" };

    String yourDate = "2017-Mar-02";
    Date date = null;
    for (String formatString : formatStrings) {
        try {
            date = new SimpleDateFormat(formatString, Locale.US).parse(yourDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
        }
    }
    DateFormat formatTo = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssz", Locale.US);
    System.out.println(formatTo.format(date));
}
```