# How to parse dates with SimpleDateFormat using Regex

Tags: java, regex, simpledateformat

In Java we can use SimpleDateFormat to parse a date like below:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date d = sdf.parse("12/21/2012"); //matched to December 21, 2012
```

but if our date changes to

```
Date d = sdf.parse("12-21-2012"); //ParseException!!
```

is there an easy way to expand this functionality to all sets of numbers by intermixing a regex? In other words, I don't care what the delimiter(s) are as long as the format matches. E.G:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM[^0-9]dd[^0-9]yyyy");
Date d = sdf.parse("12/21/2012"); //matched to December 21, 2012
Date d = sdf.parse("12-21-2012"); //matched to December 21, 2012
```

Comment: I cannot more strongly advise against using the legacy `java.util.Date` class.  You should find the appropriate class for your use case in the `java.time` package.

Comment: You can't do this directly, but perhaps you want to create your own class that extends the abstract parent class of SimpleDateFormat: DateFormat.

Comment: [How to parse dates in multiple formats using SimpleDateFormat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024544/how-to-parse-dates-in-multiple-formats-using-simpledateformat)

Comment: why don't you just try ... str.replaceAll("-","//");
?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use java.text.SimpleDateFormat with generic format. You need to have a clearly defined format when you want to parse or format a java.util.Date.