# Java date time format check and reset

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, datetime-parsing

String is an input and i have to check whether it is in any of these formats. If it is in sdf1 format then pass, if it is in sdf2,3.... then i add the missing the format and parse it with sdf1 format

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ssa");
SimpleDateFormat sdf3 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a");
SimpleDateFormat sdf3 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mma");
SimpleDateFormat sdf3 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm");
SimpleDateFormat sdf3 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Here is what i have

```
try{
            // Parse if it is MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a
            cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(sdf1.parse(inStr));
          }catch(Exception exp){
             try{
               cal = Calendar.getInstance();
               //Parse if it is MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ssa                      
               sdf2.parse(inStr);                 
               inStr = new StringBuilder(inStr).insert(str.length()-2, " ").toString();
               cal.setTime(sdf1.parse(inStr));
              }catch(Exception dte2){
                try{
                    cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    //Parse if it is MM/dd/yyyy hh:mma
                    sdf3.parse(inStr);
                    //if pass then set 00:00:00 AM
                    inStr = inStr+" AM";
                    inStr = new StringBuilder(inStr).insert(str.length()-2, ":00").toString();
                    cal.setTime(sdf1.parse(inStr));
```

it keeps going like try parsing and if failed in exception block check for the next one.
Is there any easy way to do this, may be in JAVA 8?
i could use the link from marked as duplicate it talks about how to parse, but i have additional requirement as auto complete with missing format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse dates in multiple formats using SimpleDateFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024544/how-to-parse-dates-in-multiple-formats-using-simpledateformat)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java 8, you can use a [`java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) with lots of optional sections - delimited by `[]`:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter
    .ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy[ hh:mm[[:ss][ ]a]][HH:mm]", Locale.US);
```

If you want just to validate the inputs - and don't assign the result to a date/time variable - just calling `parse` is enough. This works for all the cases below:

```
fmt.parse("10/20/2018");
fmt.parse("10/20/2018 10:20");
fmt.parse("10/20/2018 10:20AM");
fmt.parse("10/20/2018 10:20 AM");
fmt.parse("10/20/2018 10:20:30AM");
fmt.parse("10/20/2018 10:20:30 AM");
```

If the input is invalid, it'll throw a `DateTimeParseException`.

Note that [there's a difference between `HH` and `hh`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns). `H` is for **hour-of-day** (values between 0 and 23), while `h` is for **clock-hour-of-am-pm** (values between 1 and 12). `H` can't be with AM/PM designator, while `h` must have AM/PM to disambiguate it. That's why there are 2 different optional sections, one with each field.

I also use `Locale.US` because AM/PM strings are localized. Although for most locales, the result is "AM" or "PM", for some others it can be lowercase ("am"), or some other values (`午後` in Japanese, for example).

If you don't set the locale, it uses the JVM default. But I prefer to set it a specific one that I know it'll work with the inputs I have.

---

To print those values again, with all the fields, it's a little bit tricky.
The inputs can have only a date (day, month, year), or a date and time (day, month, year, hour, minute), so one alternative is to use a `LocalDateTime` (and set the missing fields when not present).

You can use `parseBest` and then check the type that was parsed:

```
// parse, try to create a LocalDateTime - if it's not possible, try a LocalDate
TemporalAccessor parsed = fmt.parseBest("10/20/2018", LocalDateTime::from, LocalDate::from);
LocalDateTime dt = null;
if (parsed instanceof LocalDateTime) {
    // LocalDateTime parsed (all fields set)
    dt = (LocalDateTime) parsed;
} else if (parsed instanceof LocalDate) {
    // LocalDate parsed (set time fields)
    dt = ((LocalDate) parsed)
        // set time (use whatever value you want - I'm using 10 AM as example)
        .atTime(LocalTime.of(10, 0));
}
```

Then you use another formatter for output - that's because the first formatter will print all the optional sections when formatting, so it'll print the hours twice. Just create another one and that's it:

```
DateTimeFormatter outputFmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a", Locale.US);
System.out.println(dt.format(outputFmt)); // 10/20/2018 10:00:00 AM
```

Comment: thank you it works perfectly for validation, but i have to get in format "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a" by adding the missing format values. Thats where i stuck.

Comment: Do you want to print the parsed values? Maybe you could create another formatter, using `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` and `parseDefaulting` - make a search and you'll find lots of examples

Comment: @Pat I've updated the answer. Not sure if that's what you need, though

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly and this what i need. Simple and perfect solution. I tried with all possible values and here is the format i used, to support single digit hour minute and i change the input string to uppercase always to support AM and am.

Comment: my latest format `DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/[uuuu][uu][ h:m[[:ss][ ]a]][ H:m[:ss]]", Locale.US);` but this format isnt works for `02/03/2018 05:00:00`, what is that missing in my format