# datetimeformat with parse best method not parsing 00:00:00

Tags: java-8, datetime-format

Related Question
[Java date time format check and reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49678922/java-date-time-format-check-and-reset)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String inStr = "03/01/2018 00:00:00";
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
        Calendar cal = null;
        try {
            DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/[uuuu][uu][ h:m[[:ss][ ]a]][ H:m[:ss]]", Locale.US);
            // parse, try to create a LocalDateTime - if it's not possible, try a LocalDate
            TemporalAccessor parsed = fmt.parseBest(inStr, LocalDateTime::from, LocalDate::from);
            LocalDateTime dt = null;
            if (parsed instanceof LocalDateTime) {
                // LocalDateTime parsed (all fields set)
                dt = (LocalDateTime) parsed;
            } else if (parsed instanceof LocalDate) {
                // LocalDate parsed (set time fields)
                dt = ((LocalDate) parsed)
                    // set time (00:00 AM default)
                    .atTime(LocalTime.of(0, 0));
            }
            ZonedDateTime zdt = dt.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
            cal = GregorianCalendar.from(zdt);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(df.format(cal.getTime()));
    }
```

Here is my code, what i am trying is parse best using the fmt and getting the output in a format "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a" i have unit tested with the answer provided in the related question, but today i found it is failing for the input "03/01/2018 00:00:00". i could figure out the issue, the above code is trying to parse in format "[ h:m[[:ss][ ]a]]" instead of [ H:m[:ss]], so is that the expected behavior ? Or is there any thing i have to change the format so that parseBest will work for my inStr.?

Comment: By the way… why are you mixing the troublesome legacy classes (`SimpleDateFormat`, `Calendar`, `GregorianCalendar`) with the modern *java.time* classes (`LocalDateTime`, `DateTimeFormatter`)? Do you understand that the *java.time* classes completely supplanted the legacy date-time classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have `[[:ss][ ]a]` as optional, `[ h:m[[:ss][ ]a]]` is matching as `[ h:m]`. You should require the `a` there and let `[ H:m[:ss]]` handle the `h:m` case.

```
"M/d/[uuuu][uu][ h:m[:ss][ ]a][ H:m[:ss]]"
```