# How to parse different date strings to LocalDate/Year?

Tags: java, unix-timestamp, date-parsing, localdate

I get list of objects from Json, each of them includes date String. There are two different formats, one is standard "yyyy-MM-dd" format, second is just year "yyyy". What is the elegant way to parse these string to unix timestamp? At the moment i am using double try-catch block with SimpleDateFormat but i would like to find better solution.

Comment: Apply chain of responsibility pattern here

Comment: You can look into this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024544/how-to-parse-dates-in-multiple-formats-using-simpledateformat

Comment: You  can really think of considering solution of @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn. However, you can also check if string length is 4 then you need to parse the date else you can use standard format.

Comment: How can you figure out a unix timestamp just from a year? Do you just want to get the time at 1 Jan 00:00 of that year?

Comment: @Sweeper I assume they expect me to do exactly what you said, get the time at 1 Jan 00:00.

Comment: *get the time at 1 Jan 00:00* You will need to decide on a time zone for that too.

Answer (score 1):

If the length is four characters long, parse as a `Year`.

```
Year y = Year.parse( input ) ;
```

How do you want to represent that as a moment? Perhaps first moment of first day of the year, in UTC?

```
LocalDate ld = y.atDay( 1 ) ;
Instant instant = ld.atStartOfDay( ZoneOffset.UTC ).toInstant() ;
```

By “Unix timestamp” did you mean a count of milliseconds since the first moment of 1970 in UTC?

```
long millis = instant.toEpochMilli() ;
```

If the input is 10 characters long, parse as a `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input ) ;
```

The do the same as seen above.

```
long millis = ld.atStartOfDay( ZoneOffset.UTC ).toInstant().toEpochMilli() ;
```

Put that all together.

```
switch ( input.length() ) {
    case 4 : return Year.parse( input ).atDay( 1 ).atStartOfDay( ZoneOffset.UTC ).toInstant().toEpochMilli() ;
    case 10 : return LocalDate.parse( input ).atStartOfDay( ZoneOffset.UTC ).toInstant().toEpochMilli() ;
    default : … throw exception, unexpected input. 
}
```